# StateNotifier with riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, riverpod

I'm trying to use riverpod stateNotifier to toggle open and close a drawer. The intent was if the drawer is open then the homescreen would shrink/grow via the AnimatedContainer. I'm not sure what the problem is but the value x and y is not being read or watch by the AnimatedContainer. Plus am I using stateNotifier correctly?

**Home screen**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SafeArea(
    child: Consumer(
      builder: (context, watch, child) {
        final drawer = watch(drawerProvider).state;
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            if(drawer.isOpen){
              context.read(drawerProvider).toggleDrawer();
            }
          },
          child: AnimatedContainer(
            transform: Matrix4.translationValues(MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * drawer.x,MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * drawer.y, 0)..scale(drawer.scale),
            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 250),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(drawer.isOpen ? 20 : 0)),
            child:Container(
                ),
            ),
          );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

**Drawer Provider**

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/all.dart';

class Drawer{
  double x,y,scale;
  bool isOpen;
  Drawer(this.x,this.y,this.scale,this.isOpen);
}

class DrawerNotifier extends StateNotifier<Drawer>{
  DrawerNotifier(Drawer state) : super(Drawer(0.5,0.1,0.8,true));
  void toggleDrawer(){
    if(state.isOpen == true){
      print(true);
      state.x = 0;
      state.y = 0;
      state.scale = 1;
      state.isOpen = false;
    }else{
      print(false);
      state.x = 0.5;
      state.y = 0.1;
      state.scale = 0.8;
      state.isOpen = true;
    }
  }
}

final drawerProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref){
  return DrawerNotifier(Drawer(0.5,0.1,0.8,true));
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65761240/consumer-not-rebuilding-ui-using-riverpod/66150314#66150314

Answer (score 1):

You're not changing the == of the Drawer itself. It's the same Object both before and after the update of its members. You need to either create overrides for == and hashCode that properly reflect the member values, or switch to a different provider that requires `notify_listeners` when the "state" is changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Drawer with ChangeNotifier{

  void toggleDrawer(){
    if(state.isOpen == true){
  
notifyListeners();
    }else{

notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

It will Work