# Consumer not rebuilding UI using riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, riverpod

I'm trying to make simple stateNotifier with riverpod. When I click the button, it'll toggle between values. I've checked the value and it changes when pressing the button. The problem is the UI is not rebuilding itself. I've checked the docs and am pretty sure I've done correctly.

**Homescreen**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Consumer(
        builder: (context, watch, child) {
          final drawer = watch(drawerProvider.state);
          return Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(drawer.isOpen.toString()),
                Text(drawer.x.toString()),
                Text(drawer.y.toString()),
                Text(drawer.scale.toString()),
                FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: (){
                    context.read(drawerProvider).toggleDrawer();
                  }
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Provider**

```
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/all.dart';

class Drawer{
  double x,y,scale;
  bool isOpen;
  Drawer(this.x,this.y,this.scale,this.isOpen);
}

class DrawerNotifier extends StateNotifier<Drawer>{
  DrawerNotifier() : super(Drawer(0,0,1,false));
  void toggleDrawer(){
    if(state.isOpen){
      state.x = 0;
      state.y = 0;
      state.scale = 1;
    }else{
      state.x = 0.5;
      state.y = 0.1;
      state.scale = 0.8;
    }
    state.isOpen = !state.isOpen;
  }
}

final drawerProvider = StateNotifierProvider((ref) => new DrawerNotifier());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

@immutable
class Drawer {
  final double x;
  final double y;
  final double scale;
  final bool isOpen;

  Drawer(this.x, this.y, this.scale, this.isOpen);

  factory Drawer.initial() {
    return Drawer(0, 0, 1, false);
  }
  Drawer copyWith({
    double x,
    double y,
    double scale,
    bool isOpen,
  }) {
    return Drawer(
      x ?? this.x,
      y ?? this.y,
      scale ?? this.scale,
      isOpen ?? this.isOpen,
    );
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Drawer(x: $x, y: $y, scale: $scale, isOpen: $isOpen)';
  }
}

class DrawerNotifier extends StateNotifier<Drawer> {
  final Drawer drawer;
  DrawerNotifier(this.drawer) : super(drawer ?? Drawer.initial());

  void toggleDrawer() {
    if (state.isOpen) {
      state = state.copyWith(x: 0, y: 0, scale: 1);
    } else {
      state = state.copyWith(x: 0.5, y: 0.1, scale: 0.8);
    }
    state = state.copyWith(isOpen: !state.isOpen);
    print("new state>> $state");
  }
}

final drawerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider((ref) => new DrawerNotifier(Drawer.initial()));

class DrawerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DrawerScreenState createState() => _DrawerScreenState();
}

class _DrawerScreenState extends State<DrawerScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Consumer(
        builder: (context, watch, child) {
          final drawer = watch(drawerProvider.state);
          return Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text(drawer.isOpen.toString()),
                Text(drawer.x.toString()),
                Text(drawer.y.toString()),
                Text(drawer.scale.toString()),
                FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () {
                  context.read(drawerProvider).toggleDrawer();
                })
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have been trying to change the code from ChangeNotifier() to StateNotifier() for 1 week. I had similar problem but solved the problem with "copyWith()" method. Thanks! 
As a side note I'm not a professional flutter developer, dont judge me :)

Comment: This is a decent and correct answer, but it does not explicitly name how or why the fix works.  The key is that you REPLACE the state object, and not simply update properties on it ...