# Consumer not rebuilding UI using riverpod ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, dart, consumer, riverpod

I was able to narrow this down to the UI not updating, the consumer is not updating with changing data. How can I get this to work properly?

The goal is for the app bar text widget to reload when the models start and end date variables change.

I checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65761240/consumer-not-rebuilding-ui-using-riverpod) similar post but he is using stateNotifier. This looks more complex and I'm just trying to learn riverpod with a simple demo...

Nothing I have tried has worked yet. I tried creating a new global provider in the screen file and that did nothing. Tried changing the way I was initializing the watch in the consumer and nothing. I have verified and it seems I'm doing everything as the documentation says [here](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading/#consumerwidget). I do not understand why this won't work. Any help and pointers is appreciated!

screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:linechart/date_range_widget.dart';
import 'package:linechart/linechart.dart';

class LineChartScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Consumer(builder: (context, watch, child) {
            final startDate = watch(dateController);
            final endDate = watch(dateController);

            final formStart = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(startDate.startDate);
            final formEnd = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(endDate.endDate);

            print(context.read(dateController).startDate);
            print(context.read(dateController).endDate);

            return Text('INCOME GRAPH --- $formStart - $formEnd');
          }),
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
          actions: [DateRangeWidget()]),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
            child: Center(
                child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: LineChart(),
            )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:date_range_picker/date_range_picker.dart' as DateRangePicker;
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final dateController = Provider((ref) => DatePickModel());

class DateRangeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        color: Colors.white,
        icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
        onPressed: () async {
          final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRangePicker.showDatePicker(
              context: context,
              initialFirstDate: context.read(dateController).startDate,
              initialLastDate: context.read(dateController).endDate,
              firstDate: DateTime(2015),
              lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 2));
          if (picked != null && picked.length == 2) {
            context.read(dateController).setDates(picked.first, picked.last);
          }
        });
  }
}

class DatePickModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  DateTime _startDate = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(seconds: 7));
  DateTime _endDate = DateTime.now();

  DateTime get startDate => _startDate;
  DateTime get endDate => _endDate;

  void setDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
    _startDate = startDate;
    _endDate = endDate;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void resetDates() {
    _startDate = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(seconds: 7));
    _endDate = DateTime.now();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

EDIT: Also tried putting widget into a separate ConsumerWidget and no go...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:linechart/date_range_widget.dart';
import 'package:linechart/linechart.dart';

class LineChartScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: AppBarTitle(),
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
          actions: [DateRangeWidget()]),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
            child: Center(
                child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: LineChart(),
            )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppBarTitle extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    context.read(dateController).formatDates();
    final formStart = watch(dateController).startFormatted;
    final formEnd = watch(dateController).endFormatted;
    return Text('INCOME GRAPH --- $formStart - $formEnd');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the type of your `Provider` to `ChangeNotifierProvider`.

A regular provider doesn't know to update when `notifyListeners` is called as it doesn't subscribe to the provided value.

```dart
final dateController = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) => DatePickModel());
```

Comment: Hey Alex, when I do this I get the error: type `'Provider<DatePickModel>' is not a subtype of type 'ChangeNotifierProvider<DatePickModel>' of 'function result'` As well as the text showing up red because the consumer does not work. Is there something else I'm doing wrong here? Thought this package should be pretty simple even for a greenie.

Comment: Also I should mention that with the Provider version as in my original code, this works i.e. the widget rebuilds to the correct last input date when I hot reload. So everything else works except the Consumer is not rebuilding when the date picker updates the values... ??

Comment: @RobbB Did you restart your app after updating your code?

Comment: I didn't think that would be necessary but it did the trick! I am now getting  an exception `The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for DatePickModel:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.` Any idea, do i need to create a constructor or initialize the two variables?

Comment: @RobbB It's probably because you are calling `formatDates` in your build method. If you open a new question I could help you there.

Comment: That would be very much appreciated! Thank you for the help so far. Here is the new Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67578010/exception-setstate-or-markneedsbuild-called-during-build