# Exception setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build

Tags: flutter, dart, exception, riverpod

Everything works perfectly, full functionality, except I get the following exception thrown on build:

```
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for DatePickModel: setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

I tried searching the error and found similar situations but none I could easily apply to this situation using riverpod. And I'm sure this isn't that big a deal however I read that if unhandled this could create a loop.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:date_range_picker/date_range_picker.dart' as DateRangePicker;
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

final dateController = ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) => DatePickModel());

class DateRangeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
        color: Colors.white,
        icon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
        onPressed: () async {
          final List<DateTime> picked = await DateRangePicker.showDatePicker(
              context: context,
              initialFirstDate: context.read(dateController).startDate,
              initialLastDate: context.read(dateController).endDate,
              firstDate: DateTime(2015),
              lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 2));
          if (picked != null && picked.length == 2) {
            context.read(dateController).setDates(picked.first, picked.last);
          }
        });
  }
}

class DatePickModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  DateTime _startDate = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 7));
  DateTime _endDate = DateTime.now();

  String startFormatted;
  String endFormatted;

  DateTime get startDate => _startDate;
  DateTime get endDate => _endDate;

  void setDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
    _startDate = startDate;
    _endDate = endDate;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void formatDates() {
    startFormatted = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_startDate);
    endFormatted = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_endDate);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void resetDates() {
    _startDate = DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(seconds: 7));
    _endDate = DateTime.now();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Screen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:linechart/date_range_widget.dart';
import 'package:linechart/linechart.dart';

class LineChartScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: AppBarTitle(),
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
          actions: [DateRangeWidget()]),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
            child: Center(
                child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: LineChart(),
            )),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppBarTitle extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    context.read(dateController).formatDates();
    final formStart = watch(dateController).startFormatted;
    final formEnd = watch(dateController).endFormatted;
    return Text('INCOME GRAPH --- $formStart - $formEnd');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, avoid using [context.read](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/reading#contextreadmyprovider) in the build method, use the `watch` parameter of the ConsumerWidget instead. You only really want to *read* a provider (as opposed to watch) in callback functions like `onPressed`, for example. The linked docs go further into this.

With that established, the reason you're getting the exception is that you're updating the state when the widget is attempting to build.

The easiest way to avoid this is using `addPostFrameCallback` to ensure the state is updated after the initial build:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
  WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    context.read(dateController).formatDates();
  });
  ...
}
```

Note that `context.read` is correct in this situation because we're using it within a callback function.

Edit:
You could also just format the dates as you set them, like so:

```dart
class DatePickModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  ...
  void setDates(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate) {
    _startDate = startDate;
    _endDate = endDate;
    formatDates(notify: false);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void formatDates({bool notify = true}) {
    startFormatted = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_startDate);
    endFormatted = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_endDate);
    if (notify) notifyListeners();
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Is the ScopedReader a must for this to work? I don’t want to always rebuild the entire widget. Maybe if I create the widget as a method that could work. But I feel there could still be issues down the road when I later choose to use a Consumer… am I on the right track of thinking here? I’m asking here not being ornery. I’m a programming noob still

Comment: @RobbB Haha, no worries! What you could do is place this all in a `Consumer` instead of a `ConsumerWidget`, that will only rebuild descendants of the `Consumer`. Though, why not just format the dates when you set them? I'll edit my answer to include my thoughts.

Comment: Finally had a chance to try this out. It works perfectly Alex! Thanks for the help! I appreciate the descriptive answer versus just code fix. Learning lots :)